# Temp table to Master table insert or update with auditing and logging

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to select the records from `temptable` and insert or update to `mastertable`. If a single field is changed, then I need to update my `history` table with the following:

- `RecordID`
- `ColumnChanged`
- `OldValue`
- `NewValue`

While performing the insert or update from the `temptable` to the `mastertable`, any errors that's occur due to foreign key violations (or any other errors) should be logged to the `error` table.

I need the history of changes and logging of errors, so that if a single record fails, I can rerun the process again.

How can I do this using T-SQL? Any code snippets will be helpful.

Here are the tables columns that I'm working with:

1. **TEMPTABLE**
   COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5
2. **MASTERTABLE**
   COL1, COL2, COL3
3. **HISTORY**
   RecordID, ColumnChanged, OldValue, NewValue
4. **ERROR**
   ErrorCode, ErrorMsg

I need to use a cursor, as I need to loop through each record when performing the inserts or updates, and to log any errors that happen during the inserting or updating due to bad data.

I need to mark the `flagcolumn` as "Y" for all successful insert or updates and "N" for all the failed records so that I can reload them again after correcting the data.

I've already used `sqlbulkcopy` to load the data in to the `temptable`.

Comment: For this type of auditing you shouldnt need a cursor, Depending on what flavor of SQL Server you have you should be able to use the output clause http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: You didn't specify which are the primary keys in the TEMPTABLE and the MASTERTABLE (even if there aren't any primary keys defined, we need to know which columns should be considered as part of the primary keys). Also, there are more columns in the TEMPTABLE than the MASTERTABLE; should we ignore the additional columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.HistoryTable
(
    HistoryTableID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    PKRecordID INT NOT NULL,
    ColumnChanged VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    OldValue VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    NewValue VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    ChangedDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE())
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ForeignKeyTableCOL2 (COL2 VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ForeignKeyTableCOL1 (COL1 VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ErrorTable
(
    ErrorTableID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    PKRecordID INT NOT NULL,
    TableName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    TablePK INT NOT NULL,
    ErrorDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    ErrorCode INT NOT NULL,
    ErrorMsg VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TempTable
(
    TempTableID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    PKRecordID INT NOT NULL,
    COL1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    COL2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    COL3 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    COL4 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    COL5 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Success CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('N')
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MasterTable
(
    PKRecordID INT NOT NULL,
    COL1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    COL2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    COL3 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    COL4 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    COL5 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.MasterTable  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_MasterTable_ForeignKeyTableCOL1 FOREIGN KEY(COL1)
REFERENCES dbo.ForeignKeyTableCOL1 (COL1)

ALTER TABLE dbo.MasterTable CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_MasterTable_ForeignKeyTableCOL1

ALTER TABLE dbo.MasterTable  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_MasterTable_ForeignKeyTableCOL2 FOREIGN KEY(COL2)
REFERENCES dbo.ForeignKeyTableCOL2 (COL2)

ALTER TABLE dbo.MasterTable CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_MasterTable_ForeignKeyTableCOL2

INSERT dbo.ForeignKeyTableCOL1 (COL1) 
VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C')
INSERT dbo.ForeignKeyTableCOL2 (COL2)
VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C')

INSERT dbo.TempTable (PKRecordID, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5)
VALUES 
    (1, 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
    (2, 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
    (3, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
    (1, 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
    (1, 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
    (1, 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
    (2, 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
    (3, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
    (4, 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D')
```

**Query:**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
      @PKRecordID INT
    , @COL1 VARCHAR(10)
    , @COL2 VARCHAR(10)
    , @COL3 VARCHAR(10)
    , @COL4 VARCHAR(10)
    , @COL5 VARCHAR(10)
    , @TempTableID INT
    , @New_Row XML
    , @Old_Row XML

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT 
          t.TempTableID
        , t.PKRecordID
        , t.COL1
        , t.COL2
        , t.COL3
        , t.COL4
        , t.COL5
        , New_Row = CAST('<r><s>' + t.COL1 + '</s><s>' + t.COL2 + '</s><s>' + t.COL3 + '</s><s>' + t.COL4 + '</s><s>' + t.COL5 + '</s></r>' AS XML)
        , Old_Row = CAST('<r><s>' + m.COL1 + '</s><s>' + m.COL2 + '</s><s>' + m.COL3 + '</s><s>' + m.COL4 + '</s><s>' + m.COL5 + '</s></r>' AS XML)  
    FROM dbo.TempTable t
    LEFT JOIN dbo.MasterTable m ON t.PKRecordID = m.PKRecordID

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO 
      @TempTableID
    , @PKRecordID
    , @COL1
    , @COL2
    , @COL3
    , @COL4
    , @COL5
    , @New_Row
    , @Old_Row

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

        IF @Old_Row IS NOT NULL BEGIN

            UPDATE dbo.MasterTable 
            SET 
                  COL1 = @COL1
                , COL2 = @COL2
                , COL3 = @COL3
                , COL4 = @COL4
                , COL5 = @COL5
            WHERE PKRecordID = @PKRecordID

            INSERT dbo.HistoryTable 
            (
                  PKRecordID
                , ColumnChanged
                , OldValue
                , NewValue
            )
            SELECT 
                  @PKRecordID
                , 'COL' + CAST(new_id AS VARCHAR(5))
                , old_value
                , new_value
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                      new_value = n.value('(.)1', 'VARCHAR(10)')
                    , new_id = 1 + n.value('for $i in . return count(../*. << $i)', 'int')
                    , old_value = o.value('(.)1', 'VARCHAR(10)')
                    , old_id = 1 + o.value('for $i in . return count(../*. << $i)', 'int')
                FROM (SELECT a = 1) d
                CROSS APPLY @New_Row.nodes('/r/s') t(n)
                CROSS APPLY @Old_Row.nodes('/r/s') k(o)
            ) data
            WHERE new_id = old_id
                AND NULLIF(new_value, '') != NULLIF(old_value, '')

            UPDATE dbo.TempTable 
            SET Success = 'Y'
            WHERE TempTableID = @TempTableID

        END
        ELSE BEGIN

            INSERT dbo.MasterTable 
            (
                  PKRecordID
                , COL1
                , COL2
                , COL3
                , COL4
                , COL5
            )
            SELECT 
                  @PKRecordID
                , @COL1
                , @COL2
                , @COL3
                , @COL4
                , @COL5           

            UPDATE dbo.TempTable 
            SET Success = 'Y'
            WHERE TempTableID = @TempTableID

        END

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        INSERT dbo.ErrorTable 
        (
              PKRecordID
            , TableName
            , TablePK
            , ErrorDateTime
            , ErrorCode
            , ErrorMsg
        )
        SELECT 
              @PKRecordID
            , 'TempTable'
            , @TempTableID
            , GETDATE()
            , ERROR_NUMBER()
            , ERROR_MESSAGE()

    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO 
          @TempTableID
        , @PKRecordID
        , @COL1
        , @COL2
        , @COL3
        , @COL4
        , @COL5
        , @New_Row
        , @Old_Row

END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

**And this possible be helpful for you:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
   ON ...
   INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    DECLARE @DocumentUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ...

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY LOCAL FOR
        SELECT DocumentUID, ...
        FROM INSERTED

    OPEN cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DocumentUID, ...

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        DECLARE 
              @BeforeChange NVARCHAR(MAX)
            , @AfterChange NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SELECT 
              @BeforeChange = (
                SELECT * 
                FROM DELETED 
                WHERE DocumentUID = @DocumentUID 
                FOR XML RAW, ROOT
              )
            , @AfterChange = (
                SELECT * 
                FROM INSERTED 
                WHERE DocumentUID = @DocumentUID 
                FOR XML RAW, ROOT
              )

        IF EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 
            FROM dbo.Documents 
            WHERE DocumentUID = @DocumentUID
        )
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO ...
            SELECT @BeforeChange, @AfterChange

        END
        ELSE BEGIN

            ...

        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DocumentUID, ...

    END

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup our schema and tables for testing

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF OBJECT_ID('TempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TempTable;
IF OBJECT_ID('MasterTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE MasterTable;
IF OBJECT_ID('ForeignKeyTableCOL1', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ForeignKeyTableCOL1;
IF OBJECT_ID('ForeignKeyTableCOL2', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ForeignKeyTableCOL2;
IF OBJECT_ID('HistoryTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE HistoryTable;
IF OBJECT_ID('ErrorTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ErrorTable;

CREATE TABLE ForeignKeyTableCOL1 (COL1 varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE ForeignKeyTableCOL2 (COL2 varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE TempTable (TempTableID int IDENTITY(1,1), PKRecordID int, COL1 varchar(10), COL2 varchar(10), COL3 varchar(10), COL4 varchar(10), COL5 varchar(10), Success char(1))
CREATE TABLE MasterTable (PKRecordID int PRIMARY KEY, COL1 varchar(10), COL2 varchar(10), COL3 varchar(10), COL4 varchar(10), COL5 varchar(10))
ALTER TABLE MasterTable ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MasterTable_ForeignKeyTableCOL1 FOREIGN KEY (COL1) REFERENCES ForeignKeyTableCOL1 (COL1)
ALTER TABLE MasterTable ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MasterTable_ForeignKeyTableCOL2 FOREIGN KEY (COL2) REFERENCES ForeignKeyTableCOL2 (COL2)
CREATE TABLE HistoryTable (HistoryTableID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, PKRecordID int, ColumnChanged varchar(50), OldValue varchar(10), NewValue varchar(10))
CREATE TABLE ErrorTable (ErrorTableID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, PKRecordID int, TableName varchar(50), TablePK int, ErrorDateTime datetime, ErrorCode int, ErrorMsg nvarchar(4000))
GO

INSERT ForeignKeyTableCOL1 SELECT 'A' UNION SELECT 'B' UNION SELECT 'C'
INSERT ForeignKeyTableCOL2 SELECT 'A' UNION SELECT 'B' UNION SELECT 'C'

INSERT TempTable SELECT  1, 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'N'
INSERT TempTable SELECT  2, 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'N'
INSERT TempTable SELECT  3, 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'N'
INSERT TempTable SELECT  1, 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'N'
INSERT TempTable SELECT  1, 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'N'
INSERT TempTable SELECT  1, 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'N'
INSERT TempTable SELECT  2, 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'N'
INSERT TempTable SELECT  3, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'N'
INSERT TempTable SELECT  4, 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'N'

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Execute the `INSERTS` and `UPDATES` with audit/error logging

```
DECLARE @PKRecordID int, @COL1 varchar(10), @COL2 varchar(10), @COL3 varchar(10), @COL4 varchar(10), @COL5 varchar(10), @TempTableID int
DECLARE @PKRecordID_OLD int, @COL1_OLD varchar(10), @COL2_OLD varchar(10), @COL3_OLD varchar(10), @COL4_OLD varchar(10), @COL5_OLD varchar(10)
DECLARE temp_cursor CURSOR FOR
 SELECT TempTableID, PKRecordID, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5 
   FROM TempTable
  ORDER BY TempTableID;
OPEN temp_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM temp_cursor
INTO @TempTableID, @PKRecordID, @COL1, @COL2, @COL3, @COL4, @COL5

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    --SELECT @idx, @COL1, @COL2, @COL3, @COL4, @COL5


    BEGIN TRY
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MasterTable WHERE PKRecordID = @PKRecordID)
          BEGIN
            SELECT @COL1_OLD = COL1
                  ,@COL2_OLD = COL2
                  ,@COL3_OLD = COL3
                  ,@COL4_OLD = COL4
                  ,@COL5_OLD = COL5
              FROM MasterTable
             WHERE PKRecordID = @PKRecordID


            UPDATE MasterTable 
               SET COL1 = @COL1
                  ,COL2 = @COL2
                  ,COL3 = @COL3
                  ,COL4 = @COL4
                  ,COL5 = @COL5
             WHERE PKRecordID = @PKRecordID


            INSERT HistoryTable (PKRecordID, ColumnChanged, OldValue, NewValue)
            SELECT @PKRecordID, 'COL1', @COL1_OLD, @COL1
             WHERE EXISTS (SELECT @COL1 EXCEPT SELECT @COL1_OLD)

            INSERT HistoryTable (PKRecordID, ColumnChanged, OldValue, NewValue)
            SELECT @PKRecordID, 'COL2', @COL2_OLD, @COL2
             WHERE EXISTS (SELECT @COL2 EXCEPT SELECT @COL2_OLD)

            INSERT HistoryTable (PKRecordID, ColumnChanged, OldValue, NewValue)
            SELECT @PKRecordID, 'COL3', @COL3_OLD, @COL3
             WHERE EXISTS (SELECT @COL3 EXCEPT SELECT @COL3_OLD)

            INSERT HistoryTable (PKRecordID, ColumnChanged, OldValue, NewValue)
            SELECT @PKRecordID, 'COL4', @COL4_OLD, @COL4
             WHERE EXISTS (SELECT @COL4 EXCEPT SELECT @COL4_OLD)

            INSERT HistoryTable (PKRecordID, ColumnChanged, OldValue, NewValue)
            SELECT @PKRecordID, 'COL5', @COL5_OLD, @COL5
             WHERE EXISTS (SELECT @COL5 EXCEPT SELECT @COL5_OLD)


            UPDATE TempTable 
               SET Success = 'Y'
             WHERE TempTableID = @TempTableID

          END
        ELSE
          BEGIN
            INSERT MasterTable (PKRecordID, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5)
            SELECT @PKRecordID, @COL1, @COL2, @COL3, @COL4, @COL5           


            UPDATE TempTable 
               SET Success = 'Y'
             WHERE TempTableID = @TempTableID 
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT ErrorTable (PKRecordID, TableName, TablePK, ErrorDateTime, ErrorCode, ErrorMsg)
        SELECT @PKRecordID, 'TempTable', @TempTableID, GETDATE(), ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH


    FETCH NEXT FROM temp_cursor
    INTO @TempTableID, @PKRecordID, @COL1, @COL2, @COL3, @COL4, @COL5
END
CLOSE temp_cursor;
DEALLOCATE temp_cursor;

-- VIEW OUTPUT
SELECT * FROM MasterTable
SELECT * FROM ErrorTable
SELECT * FROM HistoryTable
SELECT * FROM TempTable
```